# Issues installing quickbooksdesktop integration extension

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am currently trying to install this extension into my magento 2.1.7 store. I unzipped the file and uploaded in the app/code directory of my site. I went through the steps and ran the following commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy.
```

Then I ran the compile command and am getting the following error:

Errors during compilation:

```
Magenest\QuickBooksDesktop\Controller\Connection\Start
Incorrect dependency in class Magenest\QuickBooksDesktop\Controller\Connection\Start 

in /home/cartcybermarkpro/public_html/app/code/Magenest/QuickBooksDesktop/Controller/Connection/Start.php

\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory already exists in context object

Total Errors Count: 1
```

looks like the same error more than once. The extension partially shows in my backend. I am not sure what I am missing as their support isn't very helpful or responsive. Any ideas how to fix this? I need to get this installed today

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright Â© 2015 Magenest. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*
* Magenest_QuickBooksDesktop extension
* NOTICE OF LICENSE
 */
namespace Magenest\QuickBooksDesktop\Controller\Connection;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Dir;
use Magenest\QuickBooksDesktop\WebConnector\Handlers\Queue ;
use Zend_Soap_Server as ZendSoapServer;
use Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory;

/**
 * Class Start
 * @package Magenest\QuickBooksDesktop\Controller\Connector
 */
abstract class Start extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var RedirectFactory
     */
    protected $redirectFactory;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_wsdl;

    /**
     * @var Queue
     */
    protected $_handlers;

    /**
     * @var ZendSoapServer
     */
    protected $_soapServer;

    /**
     * @var Request
     */
    protected $_requestWebapi;

    /**
     * Start constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Reader $configReader
     * @param Queue $handlers
     * @param ZendSoapServer $soapServer
     * @param RedirectFactory $redirectFactory
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Reader  $configReader,
        Queue $handlers,
        ZendSoapServer $soapServer,
        RedirectFactory $redirectFactory,
        Request $request
    ) {
        $wsdlBasePath = $configReader->getModuleDir(Dir::MODULE_ETC_DIR, 'Magenest_QuickBooksDesktop') . '/wsdl/';
        $this->_wsdl = $wsdlBasePath . 'QBWebConnectorSvc.wsdl';
        $this->redirectFactory = $redirectFactory;
        $this->_handlers = $handlers;
        $this->_soapServer = $soapServer;
        $this->_requestWebapi = $request;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException
     * @throws \Zend_Soap_Server_Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $method = $this->_requestWebapi->getHttpMethod();
        if ($method != Request::HTTP_METHOD_POST) {
            $resultRedirect =$this->redirectFactory->create();

            return $resultRedirect->setPath('/');
        }

        $soapClass = $this->_soapServer;
        $soapClass->setWsdl($this->_wsdl);
        $soapClass->setObject($this->getHandler());
        $soapClass->handle();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getHandler()
    {
        return $this->_handlers;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that they inject in the constructor the class

```
\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory
```

even if they can take it from the context object like

```
$context->getResultRedirectFactory();
```

Replace the variable assignment they do for the resultRedirectFactory with the code above

Comment: WHere would I go about doing this?

Comment: I am new to magento and not really sure what you are asking me to do. Any additional information would help

Comment: please post the code of the file /home/cartcybermarkpro/public_html/app/code/Magenest/QuickBooksDesktop/Controller/Connection/Start.php

Comment: I have gone in and edited the question and paste the code

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: remove the following lines  use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory; and         RedirectFactory $redirectFactory, and replace the line         $this->redirectFactory = $redirectFactory; with $context->getResultRedirectFactory(); .Hope this will fix your problem.